# Open/Update CGI files on VSCODE ( written in c++ )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Currently I have a working codes using C++ codes.

The currently files are legacy codes from previous developer.

Now we're trying to change a bit changes from the codes.

As of now the file extension of the files are `.cgi`

I used Notedpad++ using c++ language just to get the codes readable. But unfortunately. I got something like this

[image]

Also I tried to open the CGI file using `vscode` with c++ language unfortunately I got something like this

[image]

I just wanna know, If I can still edit the cgi files. Or any recommendations for doing that

Comment: Sure, if you open this in a disassembler, you'll get readable _assembly_ code.  You haven't clearly described the situation, but it sounds like you have a binary that was compiled from C++ code, you have somehow lost the original code, and now you want to modify it.  You can't get the original code back.  You _might_ have some luck if you use a C++ decompiler, but chances are you'll just end up with a huge mess and it'd be easier to rewrite the entire thing from scratch.

Comment: You might consider wrapping the old binary from your new code.  In other words, have your new code determine which pathways should be handled by the legacy system and invoke that when necessary.  And otherwise, do everything inside your new program.  However, based on the nature of your question, this might be beyond your reach.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to contact the original developer and see if they can provide the source code.

Comment: This is helpful will try contacting the original developer and do necessary action. Thanks for this info